# How to add an attribute to a user?

Tags: users, user-meta

I have looked for an answer, and couldn't find a clear and relevant answer yet.

I want to add more attribute to the users not to display, but only store information about them. The information will be used for a background function. I know that usermeta is used to add more attributes, and I know how to access the already existing information, but I don't know how to add/create new attributes.

This piece of information can be a null string by default for every user and modified if the user enters information.

I'd appreciate any kind of help since I'm new at Wordpress. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest trick is to use the `user_contactmethods` - the fields don't actually have to be contacts, but WordPress will do all the leg work for you (displaying the fields & saving the data):

```
function wpse_183763_user_contactmethods( $methods, $user ) {
    $methods['my_field_1'] = 'My Label For Field 1';
    $methods['my_field_2'] = 'My Label For Field 2';

    return $methods;
}

add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'wpse_183763_user_contactmethods', 10, 2 );
```

If you add this code to a plugin or your `functions.php`, you'll see the new fields when editing your profile. To get the values, just use the meta API:

```
// With a user ID
echo get_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_field_1', true );

// Or with a WP_User object
echo $user->my_field_1;
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but what do parameters 10 and 2 stand for in the add_filter function?

Comment: `10` is the priority (for a filter/action that has multiple functions hooked to it, they are executed in order from the lowest number to the highest), and `2` is the number of accepted arguments. Check out [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hook_to_WordPress).

Comment: I added your exact code to my functions.php(only changed the field names) and made sure this ran in a template: update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_booked_lesson', 'Languages of Europe'); But I don't see any row created in the database. Do I need to do one more thing?

Comment: Are you defining `$user_id`? It sounds from your comment that my answer isn't actually what you need. My code will add fields to the user profile, but if you just need to read/save meta, just use the `*_user_meta` functions.